# My Star Wars : Battlefront won't run outside of Demo mode

Tags: star-wars-battlefront-2015

I bought a physical copy of Star Wars Battlefront for PlayStation 4, inserted it in my console, and let it update.

After it was finished updating, I ran the game, and was shown an installation screen. It says `"Embrace the Dark Side of the Force."` in yellow text, at the top, and `"Wipe out as many Revels scum as you can while Battlefront Installs."` in smaller white text.

When I check for updates through the PS menu, it tells me `"Your game has no further updates"`.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was Restart the Console,

You hit the PS Button then go up to the Power button press it, then go down to Power Options and press Restart.

Comment: Probably the game just needed to be closed and relaunched after a short time, for it to finish installing all its pieces.

Comment: @GnomeSlice That is what I was thinking

Answer (score 1):

Check and see if you have any other downloads taking place for other games. If you do, just pause them. That was my case. Hope it helps.